# SQL Having MAX(COUNT) error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello guys I am having a problem which is eating me for hours. What I am trying to do is count how many rows have same value from table t2 and show only max values not all of them. But I get error. How I can solve this problem? I can't find specific answer.

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>       Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

.

```
SELECT t1.operatoriausPavadinimas,count(t2.operatoriausID) as ct
FROM Operatorius t1,Planas t2
WHERE t1.operatoriausID=t2.operatoriausID 
Group by t1.operatoriausPavadinimas
Having COUNT(t2.operatoriausID)>=MAX(COUNT(t2.operatoriausID))
```

Comment: tag your dbms, show some sample data and the expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct; nested aggregation functions do not make sense (although nesting aggregation functions inside window functions does make sense).  One simple approach uses window functions, which are available in most databases:

```
SELECT op.*
FROM (SELECT o.operatoriausPavadinimas, count(p.operatoriausID) as ct,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count(p.operatoriausID) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Operatorius o JOIN
           Planas p
           ON o.operatoriausID = p.operatoriausID 
      GROUP BY o.operatoriausPavadinimas
     ) op
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases that are abbreviations are better than random names like `t1` and `t2` (or `a` and `b`).
- Learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

EDIT:

Okay, in SQL Server, the easiest is `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
      SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES o.operatoriausPavadinimas, count(p.operatoriausID) as ct
      FROM Operatorius o JOIN
           Planas p
           ON o.operatoriausID = p.operatoriausID 
      GROUP BY o.operatoriausPavadinimas
      ORDER BY COUNT(p.operatoriausID) DESC
```